# Vue serve issue

Tags: vue.js, development-environment

I've just installed Vue CLI on my VDS but have an issue with serving my app.

**`npm run serve --host $IP --port $PORT`**

```
> client@0.1.0 serve /home/ubuntu/workspace/testapp/client
> vue-cli-service serve "0.0.0.0" "8080"

 INFO  Starting development server...
 94% after seal

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
13:49:58

This dependency was not found:

* /home/ubuntu/workspace/testapp/client/0.0.0.0 in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client/index.js (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./0.0.0.0

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /home/ubuntu/workspace/testapp/client/0.0.0.0
```

So, what dependencies should I install? I thought it was installed within Vue CLI already...

Vue: 3.1.1

Node: 8.9.4

Comment: Did you try `vue-cli-service serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080`?

Comment: @ittus, this is the result: `bash: vue-cli-service: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I can't just write proxy for my VDS via Vue CLI `serve` command but I fixed it by adding `vue.config.js` file in the root of the app with this config:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'https://example.com/',
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

Then `npm run serve` and as a result it works on my remote VDS.